# Do all PowerEdge servers have thermal CPU protection?

Tags: dell-poweredge, physical-environment

Cant seem to find anyhting about it. I could test it tho, but a quicky for anyone having the answer. Do all PowerEdge servers have a upper CPU temp limit for shutting down?

I'm currently playing with my old 2650, so will it turn off if it gets too hot?

Comment: [Manuals and Documents for PowerEdge 2650](http://www.dell.com/support/Manuals/us/en/19/Product/poweredge-XEO2650)

Comment: I have never seen a modern computer (say, one with ACPI) that doesn't have thermal protection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is; yes.  Most if not all motherboards (BIOS) have this feature built in to save the processor(s). These settings normally can be changed to enable/disable and change temperature value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes... but if you're at the point where your CPUs are in danger of overheating, there would be many more indicators that would be be triggered first: e.g. increased fan speed, storage backplane alerts, power supply, etc.